# Gatling URLencode Feeder Session in the Query Param

Tags: scala, gatling

I am using the Gatling feeder to fetch the tokens from the CSV file and use the tokens as the query param of the request.
But the query param is appending the tokens with some HTML numeric character references. I want to use the token as it is, so I am using the java.net.URLEncoder.encode but seems to not work with the session.

```
private val tokenFeeder = csv(System.getProperty("user.dir")+"/src/gatling/resources/tokenCSV/tokens.csv").
    convert { case ("TOKEN", t) => "".concat(t) }.circular

execute.apply(
    scenario("service")
      .feed(tokenFeeder)
      .exec(LandingPage.getlandingPage)
  )

object LandingPage {
    val getlandingPage: HttpRequestBuilder = http("Launch App Page")
      .get(URLS.LANDING)
      .queryParam("""token""", java.net.URLEncoder.encode(s => s"${s.attributes("TOKEN")}", "UTF-8"))
      .check(status.is(200))
  }
```

Comment: Please provide information about your actual issue. Here, you're asking help on a broken implementation of what you think is a good solution but might as well be wrong. What does your tokens look like in your CSV file and how do you think Gatling is corrupting them? `queryParam` performs the URL encoding.

Comment: Something like UoLbjfc3O25wqkOqjOzU5%2FHfZcxZ8GaT7T3FHYQa70oX2u%2BOymh%2BJEl0KjhfvvHiqFLddXXdAt0Zgd0%2BjtKdCorz1yQqJSSQxZ46yJHRj6BcfjvHxwSsmNuj13iTafY2GyuxWh7LtFdOjRVOVhJAJ51sFQ85otQ%2FxBMe2UijNzQSYHzmg%2F8M0%2B3u8PoLACouDGWVirBkgNfpUJggIZt2h5qRlu0fY4wDNieSPM6pkkrEVCTqVf8%2BkNqk%2F6lM

Comment: Please edit your question instead. And provide value before (CSV) and after (as sent by Gatling).